# Django: Redirect to object generates weird URL

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, shortcut

I'm following the first example from the [Django documentation for django.shortcuts.redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples). When I call redirect on my object, it redirects to the URL 
`<bound method Event.get_absolute_url of <Event: Blah 2014>>` when really it should be calling that get_absolute_url method and redirecting to the URL returned by the function. Actually calling myevent.get_absolute_url() correctly returns '/1/right-slug', but redirect, which should just be calling this function, doesn't work right.

For reference, below are snippets of the model, the view and the URLConf.

models.py:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateField()


    @property
    def slug(self):
        return slugify(str(self))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('event-with-slug', kwargs={'event_id': self.id, 'slug': self.slug})
```

views.py:

```
def event_offers(request, event_id="1", slug=""):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)

    if event.slug != slug:
        return redirect(event, permanent=True)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^event/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$', view=views.event_offers, name='event-without-slug'),
url(r'^event/(?P<event_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', view=views.event_offers,
                       name='event-with-slug'),
```

Request: www.example.com/1/wrong-slug

Expected redirect to: wwww.example.com/1/right-slug

Actual redirect to: www.example.com/1/wrong-slug/>

Comment: Does your `get_absolute_url` return slug variable value that starts with "slug-"?

Comment: get_absolute_url() returns the string '/1/right-slug', which is the same as the slug generated by the slug() function I defined. Why does it need to start with 'slug-'?